# R plot_ly(): adding multiple vertical lines to a plot based on time data

Tags: r, dataframe, plotly, r-plotly

I need some help plotting multiple vertical lines based on time data.
My data frame with the time data is defined as following:

```
v.years <- as.Date(c("2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2009-01-01",
                     "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01",
                     "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01"))
df.dateYears <- as.data.frame(v.years)
```

My code for the plot looks like this:

```
p <- plot_ly(dt.allDataFvsS, x = dt.allDataFvsS$date, y = dt.allDataFvsS$meanDifference, mode = 'lines',
             type = 'scatter', line = list(color = "#007d3c"), text = ~forwardProduct, 
             hovertemplate = paste("<b>%{text} vs. Spot</b><br>", "%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br>",
                                   "%{yaxis.title.text}:  %{y}<br><extra></extra>")) %>%
     add_trace(x = as.Date("2018-10-01"), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(color = "red", dash = "dash"), text = "Price Zone Separation",
               hovertemplate = paste("<b>%{text}</b><br>", "%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br><extra></extra>")) %>%
     layout(title = "Average Price Difference Forward vs. Spot", xaxis = list(title = "Date"), 
            yaxis = list(title = "EUR/MWh"), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
```

I know how to do it for a single date as you can see in my code above, where I used following:

`trace_add(x = as.Date("2018-10-01"), ...)`

My plot looks actually like this:
[Rplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pabxt.jpg)

So, my question is: **How do I plot multiple vertical lines exactly matching the time data in my data frame `df.dateYears`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `add_trace` in a loop:

```
library(plotly)

dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2004-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = 12)
dt.allDataFvsS <- data.frame(date = dates, meanDifference = seq_along(dates))

v.years <- as.Date(c("2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2009-01-01",
                     "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01",
                     "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01"))
df.dateYears <- as.data.frame(v.years)


p <- plot_ly(dt.allDataFvsS, x = dt.allDataFvsS$date, y = dt.allDataFvsS$meanDifference, mode = 'lines',
             type = 'scatter', line = list(color = "#007d3c"), text = ~"forwardProduct", 
             hovertemplate = paste("<b>%{text} vs. Spot</b><br>", "%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br>",
                                   "%{yaxis.title.text}:  %{y}<br><extra></extra>")) %>%
  add_trace(x = as.Date("2018-10-01"), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = "red", dash = "dash"), text = "Price Zone Separation",
            hovertemplate = paste("<b>%{text}</b><br>", "%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br><extra></extra>")) %>%
  layout(title = "Average Price Difference Forward vs. Spot", xaxis = list(title = "Date"), 
         yaxis = list(title = "EUR/MWh"), showlegend = FALSE)


for(v.year in df.dateYears$v.years){
  p <- add_trace(p, x = as.Date(v.year, origin = "1970-01-01"), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = "red", dash = "dash"), text = "Price Zone Separation",
            hovertemplate = paste("<b>%{text}</b><br>", "%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br><extra></extra>"))
}

p
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this approach using a loop and the original vector of dates you mentioned in the question. I have added example data and modified your date vector but with your original data it must work fine:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
#Sample data
mydata <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'),as.Date('2021-12-31'),length.out = 30),
                     meanDifference=round(runif(30,0,15),0),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
p <- plot_ly(mydata, x = ~date, y = ~meanDifference, mode = 'lines',
             type = 'scatter', line = list(color = "#007d3c"), text = ~meanDifference)
#New data
v.years <- as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01"))
#Add lines with loop
for(i in 1:length(v.years))
{
  p <- p %>%
    add_trace(x = v.years[i], type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
              line = list(color = "red", dash = "dash"), text = "Price Zone Separation")
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have another question to your solution: 
I'm using your version, but unfortunately it doesn't plot the vertical lines long enough. What I mean is that the lines on the y-axis start at about 28 and go to 57. In some cases, however, my graphic goes beyond 65 (y-axis).

I would like to post a picture of the plot in the comments, but you can't.

Comment: @Michi It must be an issue of layout, you have to check the setting of layout and add to the loop. It is a possibility of what to do in your case!